# Merge four arrays with common value

Tags: php, arrays

I have four arrays as like below

```
$array1 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","url":1},{"month":"February","url":102},{"month":"March","url":192}]', true);
$array2 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","ip":12},{"month":"June","ip":10}]', true);
$array3 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","domain":120},{"month":"February","domain":200},{"month":"June","domain":100}]', true);
$array4 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","file":80},{"month":"June","file":10}]')
```

My expected output will be

```
$result=[{"month":"January","url":1,"ip":12,"domain":120,"file":80},{"month":"February","url":102,"domain":120},{"month":"March","url":192,"domain":120},{"month":"June","ip":10,"domain":100,"file":10}]
```

i have tried like this and i am able to get for two arrays. but i am not able to get four arrays.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as &$item) {
if (empty($array2))
    break;

foreach ($array2 as $key => $item2) {
    if ($item['month'] === $item2['month']) {
        $item = array_merge($item, $item2);
        unset($array2[$key]);
        continue;
    }
}
}
if (!empty($array2))
$array1 = array_merge($array1, $array2); 

echo json_encode($array1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `next` function to get the second element from your associative array and fetch the key using `key` function:

```
$array1 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","url":1},{"month":"February","url":102},{"month":"March","url":192}]', true);
$array2 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","ip":12},{"month":"June","ip":10}]', true);
$array3 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","domain":120},{"month":"February","domain":200},{"month":"June","domain":100}]', true);
$array4 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","file":80},{"month":"June","file":10}]', true);

$array5 = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);

$finalArr = [];
foreach ($array5 as $value) {
    $finalArr[$value['month']]['month'] = $value['month'];
    next($value);
    $finalArr[$value['month']][key($value)] = $value[key($value)];
}

echo json_encode(array_values($finalArr), true);
```

Gives:

```
[{"month":"January","url":1,"ip":12,"domain":120,"file":80},{"month":"February","url":102,"domain":200},{"month":"March","url":192},{"month":"June","ip":10,"domain":100,"file":10}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$array1 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","url":1},{"month":"February","url":102},{"month":"March","url":192}]', true);
$array2 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","ip":12},{"month":"June","ip":10}]', true);
$array3 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","domain":120},{"month":"February","domain":200},{"month":"June","domain":100}]', true);
$array4 = json_decode('[{"month":"January","file":80},{"month":"June","file":10}]', true);

$result = [];

foreach ( [$array1, $array2, $array3, $array4] as $row )
{
    foreach ( $row as $item )
    {
        $month = $item['month'];
        if ( isset($result[$month]) )
        {
            $item = array_merge($result[$month], $item);
        }

        $result[$month] = $item;
    }
}

var_dump(array_values($result));
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Anyhow i used array_replace_recursive to achieve this.